# Physics of a Second quantized Hamiltonian?

Tags: second-quantization, bosons

It is frequently seen that the (Bosonic) Hamiltonian $H=e a^{\dagger}a+f( a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}+a a)$ is discussed and diagonalized using Bogoliubov transformation. My question is that what is physical interpretation of last two terms? Is there a real situation described by such Hamiltonian?
Note that particle number is not conserved.

Comment: Quick hint : Squeezing and squeezed states of photons generated in optical parametric down conversion in quantum optics for example generated by passing classical light through non-linear crystal.

Comment: I am not sure about bosonic Hamiltonians of this form. But one example that immediately came to my mind is the BCS ground state Hamiltonian which will look similar to this form after using Wick's Theorem for a mean field decoupling.